# Comments in Minecraft Crash Reports

Tags: discussion, minecraft

**Please let me know if this is a bad place for this post.** I initially thought of posting it on the main Arqade page, but this *technically* isn't about the game, and then again *technically*, it's not about the site either...

So anyway. I have noticed a lot of Minecraft Crash Reports have a "tag line" comment, and I thought about looking into it to see if it means anything.

For example, some comments I have found are:

```
// Daisy, daisy...
// I'm sorry, Dave.
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.
// You're mean.
```

These are just some of the "comments" I have found in Crash reports, and I was wondering if they meant anything. If so, could they possibly be used to collate an index for dealing with crash reports on site?

For example, `//Daisy, daisy...` might refer to an issue with Java, or `//I'm sorry Dave` could be a mod clash?

Comment: Just [Easter Eggs](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148029/what-are-the-minecraft-easter-eggs/148114#148114), pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't really relate to anything in particular

> Witty comments are phrases shown at the top of crash reports generated using the process shown earlier in this article. They do not show on crash screens and are similar in nature to splashes. They can be changed by changing your minecraft.jar .class files. They get selected using the system time in nanoseconds.

[Source](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Crash#Witty_comments)

since they are selected based off the nanoseconds portion of the system time they are kinda random and can't really be used to help moderate questions

Comment: Damn. thought I was onto something there. I really feel like we need to get this issue in hand...

Comment: @Ben if your referring to [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10088/30879) remember we're dealing with a human element. the best thing we can do is put up signs as clear as day so that anyone who ignores them will look like an idiot and can't argue when no one helps them. the only way we can treuly fix this is something like [this](http://somethingofthatilk.com/index.php?id=170). except the user's head is bashed into the screen forcing them to read and wont let go until they have read everything

Comment: True. Until then I find looking for any extra hints or details hidden in plain sight could be helpful.